# Enemy Boss movement AI

Tags: unityscript

Good day to all, I am trying to get an enemy boss ship to appear on screen and attack my ship and also dodge my attacks sometimes. So far I have gotten him to attack my ship but hes stays on the edge of the screen. Here is my code :

```
#pragma strict

// here are public variables for the enemy ship that can be accessed in the inspector
var health:int = 2;
var explosion:GameObject;
var expOrb:GameObject;
var enemyBullet:GameObject;
var expDrop:int = 3;
var hitSound:AudioClip;
var fireRate:float = 2.0;

//heres the private variable counter to keep track of time for fire rate.
private var counter:float = 0.0;

function Update () {
   //here we make counter count based on time for the fire rate
   counter += Time.deltaTime;

   //if the ship goes too far left, we destroy it.
   if(transform.position.x < -12){
      Destroy(gameObject);
   }

   //here we shoot 4 bullets if the counter counts higher than the fire rate.
   if(counter > fireRate){
      var custom1 = Instantiate(enemyBullet, transform.position - Vector3(0.5,0.1,0), Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
      var custom2 = Instantiate(enemyBullet, transform.position - Vector3(0.5,0.1,0), Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
      var custom3 = Instantiate(enemyBullet, transform.position- Vector3(0.5,0.1,0), Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
      var custom4 = Instantiate(enemyBullet, transform.position- Vector3(0.5,0.1,0), Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
      //to make the bullets spread, we add extra z velocity to each one to they all move on their own path.
      custom1.rigidbody.velocity.z = 3;
      custom2.rigidbody.velocity.z = 1;
      custom3.rigidbody.velocity.z = -1;
      custom4.rigidbody.velocity.z = -3;
      counter = 0.0;
   }

   //end of function update
}

//if a bullet hits the ship, the bullets sends us the hit message to trigger this function to bring down the ships health
function hit () {
   health -= 1;
   if(health != 0){
      if(audio.enabled == true){
         audio.PlayOneShot(hitSound);
      }
   }
   if(health <= 0){
      onDeath();
   }
}

//if health is 0, then this function is triggered to spawn some orbs, spawn the explosion animation object, and destroy itself
function onDeath () {
   Instantiate(expOrb,transform.position,Quaternion.Euler(-90,0,0));
   expDrop -= 1;
   if(expDrop <= 0){


       Instantiate(explosion,transform.position,Quaternion.Euler(-90,Random.Range(-180,180),0));
       Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    if(expDrop > 0){
       onDeath();
    }
 }
```

How do i add the movement aspect to it?

Comment: What have you already tried? Why didn't it work? What documents have you reviewed before deciding to ask this question here? You might also want to whittle down your code example a bit to let us focus on where and what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to move an object, you can try:

1. `Transform.translate` (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)
2. Modifying `transform.position` (http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/188998/transformposition.html)
3. Adding force to it (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)
4. And many other ways that I may have not known yet.

For a boss in this kind of game, the movement you may want is either random movement or following the player. Both are not hard to achieve.

- Random movement: just do a `Random.Range(-1, 1) * bossSpeed *
  time.deltaTime` and apply it to the boss' x position.
- Following the player: get the player's x position then make the boss adjust to the position.

Then how to make the boss dodge the player's bullet sometimes? You can make the boss detect if a player's bullet is incoming by adding a collider thats stands in front of it. If a player's bullet collide with it, then random another number (eg. from 0 to 1). Afterwards, you just need to move the boss away if the random number is 1 and don't move the boss when the random number is 0.

Comment: why do you guys minus a question?.... that's rude. Now i cant ask anymore questions.